# Apache RewriteCond with Variables

Tags: apache, variables, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect to a URL only when the cookie does not match the URL request like so:

```
URI: http://mywebsite/myapp/myservice/my123token
COOKIE: MYCOOKIE=my456token


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/myservice/(.*)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} .*MYCOOKIE="(.*);?.*
RewriteRule .* http://mywebsite/myapp/myservice/%1
```

So what's happening is that the incoming request comes with token **my123token** but the cookie has token **my456token** only then should Apache redirect to the shown url using the URI token value.

So the question is how do I implement the second condition so that the rewrite rule is only applied when the tokens don't match.

I feel this would somehow involve using variables but not sure how, please help. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a backreference inside the regex. Of the top of my hat:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} .*MYCOOKIE=(.*);?.*
RewriteCond $1=%1 !^(.*)=\1$
RewriteRule myapp/myservice/(.*) /myapp/myservice/%1 [L,R=302]
```

Note the `=` is just used as some separator.

PS. I removed the `"` from the rewriteCond as your cookie doesn't seem to contain any.